# Why and How does copying and pasting a "problem" model with errors in it into a new empty model fix the model (ArcGIS, ModelBuilder)

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder

I often work with ModelBuilder and Models that have previously worked seem to become unstable or develop issues after lots of editing. They return error messages for parts of the model that did not previously return errors.

A solution often recommended is to simply copy and paste the contents of the model into a new empty model.

Does anyone have expertise or advice to share that can explain why this fixes models and if this is likely to be a permanent fix?

I am developing a set of models that I will be sharing and I need them to be robust enough that they work for the model users.

One of the reasons I am asking this is that often when contacting ESRI support they will focus entirely on the reported error messages within ModelBuilder even when you tell them the Model has previously worked OK, or that it runs OK on a different computer or from the Edit vs open window. It seems to me that very often the error messages returned by models are of no use at all, especially when the problem for example is fixed by copying and pasting into a new empty model.

Is it that these error messages are a symptom of a model that is becoming unstable?

Comment: Does it happen even when you restart the whole application? If not then I guess variables are kept between model runs and there is something unclean in your code.